# DNS configuration with separate accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb, aws-route53

I have an AWS setup where I have a main AWS account (MainAccount), where I have a public hosted zone for my domain (mydomain.com) and also registered the domain under this account. Then I have a separate AWS account (AppAccount) where I deploy my applications using VPCs and Load balancers. Currently I add a CNAME record that points to the loadbalancer DNS for each app (like app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com) to be able to reach them.

It is working OK, but I have to switch to the main account to add a new record all the time if I want to set up a new app. I'm looking for a way to be able to set up a new app without doing any modification to the MainAccount (while I still keep the public hosted zone and domain registration on that account).

I've been trying to read up this a bit and I think I found two ways to make it work, but I the whitepapers/examples are quite complicated and I didn't actually make it work, so I'm wondering what I might do wrong and how can it be done properly.

One way I tried is:

- Add a public hosted zone to the AppAccount like app1.mydomain.com
- Add an aliased A record under this hosted zone that points to my app's load balancer DNS
- (repeat both steps for every new app)

This way I'm not able to reach the app from the internet

Another way is:

- Add a private hosted zone to AppAccount like mydomain.com (I believe this is the concept of domain overlapping in AWS)
- Add an A or CNAME record for the app's load balancer DNS
- (repeat last step for each new app)

I also didn't managed to make this work

How can I achieve a similar setup that works?

PS: I'm using AWS CLI to set up the apps